# Activity reset view on orientation change

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have some problems with Android Activity's orientation changes.

I have a game and some flying balloons on it. Balloon (`ImageViews`) are created dynamically, so they are flying. But when I change device orientation (to port or land) activity is re-creating and my balloons are disappearing. Same thing happens when I move to the next activity and then go back to my balloons activity.

Is there any way to "save" my dynamically created balloons (and it's position and other properties) on my activity

I also tried `getLastNonConfigurationInstance() / onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`  but it seems to me that it's work with data, not `View` elements (may be because parent of these views is previous activity)

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private Button btn;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void createBtn(Context context, LinearLayout layout) {
        if (btn == null) {
            btn = new Button(context);
            layout.addView(btn);
        }
    }
}


public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
        s.createBtn(this, ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.baseLayout)));
    }
}
```

Button will not appear at second onCreate (on change orientation) (I think the problem is that Button's Context is previous Activity)

### Updated code:

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    private Button btn;
    private SparseArray<Parcelable> container;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void createBtn(Context context, LinearLayout layout) {
        if (btn == null) {
            btn = new Button(context);
            layout.addView(btn);
            btn.setText("Hello");
            saveBtn();
        } else if (container != null){
            btn = new Button(context);
            btn.restoreHierarchyState(container);
            layout.addView(btn);
        }
    }

    public void saveBtn() {
        container = new SparseArray<Parcelable>();
        btn.saveHierarchyState(container);
    }

}
```

I think that on new Button should appear "Hello" text, but it's doesn't happen. Whats wrong?

Comment: That looks totally fine to me. What difference does it do?

Comment: not working( you can test it [from there](http://zarrina.net/test2.zip)

Comment: Check if your container really contains the values before restoring. log the values. if values are missing then it means container reference is lost while recreating the activity. Remove `if (container != null)` line. If btn is not null then container also should not be null.

Comment: container is not null. I have debug it and no I think the problem is that saveHierarchyState is not working, because after saving container is not null, but all objects in it are nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `onSaveInstanceState()` callback in your activity. Save all the data to the bundle you receive in this method. In `onCreate` of your activity check the `savedInstance` bundle for null. If its not null, read back and apply the data to your views.

### Update

Don't check for null in `createBtn` method.

```
public void createBtn(Context context, LinearLayout layout) {
        btn = new Button(context);
        layout.addView(btn);
}
```

### Update 2

Make the `container` variable static. I think you are losing the values when activity restarts.

Comment: see my example, I think then you will understand my problem

Comment: you said "apply the data to your views". Do you mean that I should save View's properties and then put this data to my new View? But there are a lot of properties that are changed. And there are animation. For example animation is playing and when user change device orientation, I want to continue animation in the new activity (created by new orientation)

Comment: I don't need to create new button. I just want my old button with it properties on the new activity. Read this: "For example animation is playing and when user change device orientation, I want to continue animation in the new activity (created by new orientation)". This animation was appended to old button and should continue on the new activity

Comment: Look. I create button; Set it's properties -text, margin, etc.; Start animate this button. Then user change device orientation. Activity is destroyed, my button too. But I want that button has appeared on the new activity with it's text, margin and its should continue animation

Comment: Then you should save the whole view's hierarchy and restore in `onCreate`. Use `saveHierarchyState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container)`to save and `restoreHierarchyState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container)` to restore.

Comment: please look new updated code on the top. something wrong with this functions

Comment: Have u really tried `onSaveInstanceState()`? I doubt. In your question I see `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and not saveinstancestate. Save all data to the state parcel u get as parameter.

Comment: I have mistake with onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() in question, but not in the project. If you want, you can look project source from there: http://zarrina.net/test2.zip

Comment: But using `onSaveInstanceState()` is the right way. What you are trying is not right. Revert back to using saveinstance and fix it. Add that code to ur question.

Comment: why do I need onSaveInstanceState ? I save my settings in singleton... Do you see my project source?

Comment: You don't need the Singleton. You can do it in saveinstancestate itself. Call `saveState(outBundle)` on your button. and restore it in oncreate.

Comment: it's doesn't matter if I use saveState or Singleton. It's all make one action. And it's not working. I'm so tired and I already have resigned myself to this problem... (((

Comment: Do you have different layouts for landscape and portrait? If not, you can prevent restart of your activity by specifying `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. And if you need to do something when orientation changes, do it in `onConfigurationChanged` callback of Activity class.

Comment: My problem still not resolved. Ive locked orientation changing. And now my application work only in one orientation( Thank you VERY VERY much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine if you store all your data in onPause() and load it back in onResume().

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Add this into your activity declaration part in the manifiest.xml file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Comment: This helped me in a different problem that I had. Thanks :)